# Emacs automatic pointer handling (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, qt-creator, emacs24

In QT Creator, a feature I found very useful was the automatic conversion from a period to arrow when dealing with pointers

For example:

```
std::string *test;
...
test->clear();
//  ^ When a period is inserted, the IDE automatically converts the dot to an arrow
```

So, I was wondering if there is an Emacs plugin which does this, or can this be done in vanilla Emacs?

(Emacs 24.3.1)

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure that QtCreator is fail-proof on this. Doing that reliably requires cooperation with the compiler (e.g. because some headers or templates might `typedef` pointers). You could use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to extend & customize [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for that purpose, but that would be a significant project (a few months of work).